# normalize json in python (for sha256 check sum)

Tags: python, json, hash, normalization, sha

We need a fixed hash of a datastructure which is serializable to json.

I am unsure if this is going to be stay constant during the next years:

```
hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)).hexdigest()
```

Is there a way to normalize json, to make it unique hashable?

Comment: There is no guarantee that it will stay constant, as things like formatting with whitespace could change in the future. If you need this guarantee, do it yourself. Apart from that, it gives a stable result, so yes, it will probably work.